# Responsive padding in email for Outlook in Windows

Tags: css, email, outlook, html-email

I've got an html email design that has responsive (left/right) padding which gets wider or narrower at 475 pixel width.  I've set the inline attributes for the narrower widths, and added media tags for responsiveness:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 476px)
{
  *[class~="iphone_pad"] {padding:0 40px;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 475px)
{   
  *[class~="iphone_pad"] {padding:0 25px;}
}
```

This works for Apple Mail and Outlook on OSX, and since the default is the narrow padding, on most major narrow screens.  But Outlook on Windows doesn't respond with the wider padding.  It may be that Outlook/Windows [doesn't support the media tag](https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/media-query-support/)?

Does anyone know of any way to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is inlined CSS in the body of the email, you should add an `!important` on the end of each CSS rule in the `<style>` tag so it can override the inline CSS.

But...

Windows Outlook supports the `<style>` tag but *not* the `@media` tag. I usually build emails that work in Outlook first and then hack/progressively enhance the layout for other clients using tags that Windows Outlook doesn't recognize (like `@media`).

Comment: Interesting.  So you're suggesting I default to the wide screen, including Outlook, by inlining the wider padding.  The question would be if all narrower screens will behave: the wider padding is more onerous on narrow screens than vice versa.

Comment: Sigh... yes that's what I do. All clients that you'd want a narrow design shuld support media queries, so you can override the wide padding.

If you don't like this route, you can wrap each section of you email in MSO ghost tables, basically creating a whole separate set of rules just for Outlook.
https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/using-ghost-columns-to-fix-alignment-problems-in-outlook. This can get quite cumbersome, though, but it's an option.

Comment: Yes, I've looked at the MSO alternative and don't like it... will let you know...

Comment: hmmmm. close. Outlook looks ok-- Gmail App on Android shows the wider margins.  I'm accepting anyway, but will have to see how important that client is, and solve some other glitches which show up... thanks!